# Lines missing in file split

Tags: c#, csv

I'm writing a program which splits a CSV file in four almost-equal parts.

I'm using a 2000-lines CSV input file as example, and when reviewing the output files, there are lines missing in the first file, and also there are uncomplete lines which makes no sense, since I'm writing line by line. Here the code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main(string[] args){

    string line; 
    int linesNumber = 0, linesEach = 0, cont = 0;

    StreamReader r = new StreamReader("in.csv");
    StreamWriter w1 = new StreamWriter("out-1.csv");
    StreamWriter w2 = new StreamWriter("out-2.csv");
    StreamWriter w3 = new StreamWriter("out-3.csv");
    StreamWriter w4 = new StreamWriter("out-4.csv");

    while((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
      ++linesNumber;

    linesEach = linesNumber / 4;

    r.DiscardBufferedData();
    r.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    r.BaseStream.Position = 0;

    while((line = r.ReadLine()) != null){
      ++cont;
      if(cont == 1){
        //fisrt line must be skipped
        continue;
      }
      if(cont < linesEach){
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        w1.WriteLine(line);
      }
      else if(cont < (linesEach*2)){
        w2.WriteLine(line);
      }
      else if(cont < (linesEach*3)){
        w3.WriteLine(line);
      }
      else{
        w4.WriteLine(line);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why is the writing part doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Well, have you stepped through each line of code in the debugger?

Comment: Example data for us to use?

Comment: What do you mean by line missing in the first file? Is this is the last line as you are counting '<' and not '<=' and what do you mean by incomplete lines? I would suggest you wrap this inside the 'using' statement and use correct encoding as this cause issues.

Comment: The StreamWriters are not being flushed. You must close StreamWriter instances to ensure that they write **all** of their data. This is most easily acheived by the `using` statement: i.e. `using(StreamWriter w1 = new StreamWriter("out-1.csv")){ doSomething(); }`

Comment: @spender So that means I must wrap the whole code in 5 `using` clauses?

Comment: @Jegan Since I'm using a 2000 lines file, the first file should have 500 lines and it has 479.

Comment: @OldProgrammer No I have not and you're right, that should've be done before asking. Sorry.

Comment: @sant016 Yes, although you can tidy things up quite a lot by omitting curlies: https://gist.github.com/biggyspender/a35beda336421c82771db5cf945c7f20

Comment: @spender I'm going to try it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is not direct answer to your question, just an alternative.

Linq can be  used to create shorter codes

```
int inx = 0;
var fInfo = new FileInfo(filename); 

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fInfo.FullName);
foreach (var groups in lines.GroupBy(x => inx++ / (lines.Length / 4)))
{
    var newFileName = $"{fInfo.DirectoryName}\\{fInfo.Name}_{groups.Key}{fInfo.Extension}";
    File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, groups);   
}
```

Comment: Never heard about linq before, thanks for showing it to me!

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your approach by using a `Partitioner` and some LINQ. It also has the benefit of only having two file handles open at once, instead of 1 for each output file plus the original input file.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FileSplitter
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        internal static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = File.ReadLines("in.csv").Skip(1);

            var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(input);
            var partitions = partitioner.GetPartitions(4);

            for (int i = 0; i < partitions.Count; i++)
            {
                var enumerator = partitions[i];

                using (var stream = File.OpenWrite($"out-{i + 1}.csv"))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, seems like something you need to know very well, I read it as complicated. I'll study it!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

The problem is, as Jegan and spender suggested, that the `StreamWriter` needs to be wrapped in the `using` clause. That said, problem solved.